# Pandas Data Reader figure not saving as image

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have successfully created a chart with stock info I am pulling from Yahoos API, but I am running into troubles when attempting to save said figure as a png.
For some reason, when I try to save the figure, it saves as just a blank png.
This is the code I am using on VS Code and Windows 10.

```
#Import Modules
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib as mpl
import plotly.express as px
#Setting Variables
start  = datetime.datetime(2010,12,31)
end = datetime.datetime(2022,9,20)


fnT = pdr.DataReader(['AMD','NVDA','INTC','TSM'],
                    'yahoo',
                    start = start,
                    end = end)['Adj Close']
#Graph 1
fnT = fnT.plot(figsize=(12,6))
plt.show()
plt.savefig('fnPlot1.png')
```

This code generates this image, but when it attempts to save, it just becomes blank.
There is no error message.
[image]
Anything helps and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pyplot.savefig` before `pyplot.show`. At the end of (a blocking) `show()` the figure is closed and thus unregistered from pyplot. Calling `pyplot.savefig` afterwards would save a new and thus empty figure.

```
plt.savefig('fnPlot1.png')
plt.show()
```